# Installation issue in Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86 version in Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: anaconda3

I have tried to install Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86 in Windows 7 (32 bit). Installation was not successful throwing error like "CONDA stopped working ". Please share me best option to install.

Answer (score 0):

`Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64` version only works with `Windows 8 and up`.

Older versions like `Anaconda3-4.0.0-Windows-x86_64 will` work with `Windows 7`